# Icon Extraction for Remote Files

Tags: c#, wpf, shell-icons

I need to show list of file from Remote Server. For this I already fetch the details of Remote server using Self Hosted Web Service. i.e. I fetch remote server file name and full path as JSON String and then show the information in TreeView [WPF]. Now I need to show the icons of these files. For this I think I Can use the icon within the client desktop application and I found 2 solution

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2532/Obtaining-and-managing-file-and-folder-icons-using#_rating

and

WPF's

```
System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon
```

However I love the solution from Later part but it doesn't work for given file name[i.e. file should present in system, which is not the case with me]. I try to run above code's sample, and Icon shown by it are not really very good or clean. So, Is there better way to extract/get Associated file Icon for extension in C#, WPF.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I search more and found the CodeProject's Article is only suggested way of extracting Icon. Though I am still experimenting it and in last 2 hours I am not able to show Icon in my Treeview though object seems filled correctly for me.